# Triangle inequality proof in Spivak's calculus

Tags: inequality, proof-verification

[image]

So hi, there's one little thing which I'm not understanding in the proof. After the inequality Spivak considers the two expressions to be equal. Why?!?

I just don't see why we can't continue with the inequality and when we have factorized the identity to $(|a|+|b|)^2$ we can just replace $(a+b)^2$ with $(|a+b|)^2$ and take the square root of both sides to finally have :

$|a+b|\le |a|+|b|$

Thank you for explaining !

Comment: I have updated your post to LaTeX. Please make sure that it is correct.

Comment: Yes, it's good thank you !

Comment: this is a shorthand notation. Each of the expressions after the $\le$ are equal. They are not equal to the stuff that precedes the $\le$.

Comment: Yeah, it makes more sense with what you told me ! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bulk of the proof is in the step where the $\le$ appears: it's clear that
$$
ab\le |a|\,|b|
$$
because the two numbers either are the same or $ab$ is the opposite of $|a|\,|b|$.

Therefore we can also say
$$
a^2+2ab+b^2\le a^2+2|a|\,|b|+b^2
$$
But the left hand side is $|a+b|^2$, while the right hand side can be written
$$
|a|^2+2|a|\,|b|+|b|^2=(|a|+|b)^2
$$

Therefore
$$
|a+b|^2 \le (|a|+|b|)^2
$$
and hence
$$
|a+b|\le |a|+|b|
$$

Why does Spivak continues with equality symbols and not $\le$? The answer is that you should read that as if it were on a single line.

Comment: Are you kidding me -____- that's why it wasn't making any sense! Thank you!

Comment: I spent a lot of time trying to understand why the equal signs lool

Comment: Well, I have another question. When Spivak justifies the passage from the squares to |a+b| <= |a|+|b| he says the following : x^2<y^2 supposes that x<y for x,y in N. Now, the only thing bugging me is the following : Why didn't he do the following x^2<=y^2  supposes that x<=y for x,y in N ? Because what he says only justifies the inequality and not the equality ! Like a part is missing ! Am I right ? Thank you!

Comment: @Astroman If $x=|a+b|$ and $y=|a|+|b|$, we have proved that $x^2\le y^2$. From this and the fact that $x\ge0$ and $y\ge0$, we should deduce that $x\le y$. If $x^2=y^2$, there's no problem. If $x^2<y^2$, then $x<y$ (easily).

Comment: Ok, I understand what you're saying but why spivak wouldn't have included the <= sign for his justification ??? Thank you again !

Comment: @Astroman Just to be fussy; deriving the equality of positive numbers from the equality of their squares is no big deal, isn't it?

Comment: Mmmh... I'm not sure if it's me not understanding you or the inverse ^^ Sorry. Anyway, I don't think it's a big detail, I just found it weird his justification ...

Answer (score 0):

For that you have to show that taking square roots preserves order (under certain assumptions).